# Change type of input from string to data, MONGO DB

Tags: json, database, mongodb, type-conversion, nosql

i'm trying to convert the `inspection_date` field from `string` to `date` for every object inside my db.
Every object is built like this one.

```
  "name": "$1 STORE",
"address": "5573 ROSEMEAD BLVD",
"city": "TEMPLE CITY",
"zipcode": "91780",
"state": "California",
"violations": [{
    "inspection_date": "2015-09-29",
    "description": "       points  ...   violation_status\n62754       1  ...  OUT OF COMPLIANCE\n62755       1  ...  OUT OF COMPLIANCE\n62756       2  ...  OUT OF COMPLIANCE\n\n[3 rows x 5 columns]",
    "risk": "Risk 3 (Low)"
}, {
    "inspection_date": "2016-08-18",
    "description": "        points  ...   violation_status\n338879       2  ...  OUT OF COMPLIANCE\n\n[1 rows x 5 columns]",
    "risk": "Risk 3 (Low)"

} //could be more than 2 or less then 2 object inside violations array//]}
```

How can i convert all of the `inspection_date` field avoiding doing it by myself one by one?

Comment: you can use `$map` operator with `$dateFromString` operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by [@turivishal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8987128/turivishal), you have to have to make use of `$map` and `$dateFromString` operators.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "violations": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$violations",
          "in": {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              "$$this",
              {
                "inspection_date": {
                  "$dateFromString": {
                    "dateString": "$$this.inspection_date",
                    "format": "%Y-%m-%d",
                    "onError": null,
                    "onNull": null
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            
          },
          
        }
      }
    }
  },
  
])
```

[Mongo Playground Sample Execution](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dyt1xS9m4p3)

Comment: thank you, it works! now we're figuring out how to save it in the database, but we are good, thank you again

Comment: Glad it helped you out. Have a look at `$merge` stage